# Failing a Jenkins job when nightwatch test assertion fails in Browserstack

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I have a Jenkins job that runs Selenium tests on Browserstack via the Nightwatch.js framework.  We have an entire suite of tests that nightwatch runs in separate processes, and we need a way to get the pass/fail value back to Jenkins after all tests have run.

I have been trying to use the Nightwatch hook `teardown` to run a piece of code at the end of each module with `if(this.results.failed) { take action }`, but I can't figure out what action I need to take in order to make the failure accessible to the Jenkins job.

My initial thought was to create an environment variable, and set it to false any time a test fails, but I think each process runs in a separate subshell, so the variables created/modified by the test module are not accessible.

My second idea was to create a counter in the globals module, but that value does not increment as expected when referenced by a global `after` method.

Comment: I don't have much experience with nodejs. but if you could exit with status code other than 0, your jenkins job will fail. try that in `{take action}`

Comment: I actually did try this, we are using the gulp-nightwatch module, and it turns out if you exit the test with status != 0, gulp-nightwatch doesn't output any details to the console.  It only prints that gulp-nightwatch encountered an error, and our reporter for that test suite fails to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using the [Jenkins Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to fail the test in the event that the console output contains the string "TEST FAILURE".

This was accomplished by creating a rule file that contains a single line:

`error /TEST FAILURE/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would recommend you do it:

- Create a **synchronised writer** in the afterEach function (https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/test-hooks.md) and write the test results to a flat file(csv, tsv, txt etc) on the system running jenkins. You may choose to write only failures *if(this.results.failed)* OR write all testIDs with pass/fail status to the file
- Once your testing build has completed, you will have all the details in the flat file (including details on failures).
- You may now trigger a downstream job (a different job on Jenkins using downstream jenkins plugin) which has a simple script(shell script) looking for failures in the test output file you wrote in step 1. Using this, Jenkins will have details if there were test failures

Note: If you have multiple independent builds running tests, please ensure you are using the **jenkins build blocker plugin** to start the downstream job after all independent builds are completed

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will test this out today!